# Monit to turn off machine when program is done

Tags: monit

I am trying to set up `monit` to turn off my virtual machine when my program is done.  (The program runs as a daemon, takes long time which I do not know in advance, and my machine is expensive so I want to save money.)

I have created the following `.monitrc` in my home directory:

```
set daemon 60
set logfile /run/monit.log
set httpd unixsocket /run/monit.socket
    allow baruch:monit
check process python3 matching python3
      start program = "sudo systemctl poweroff"
```

I have created the log file and the socket file and made them writable.

Still `monit monitor all` the gives two errors:

> /home/baruch/.monitrc:6: Program does not exist: 'sudo'
>
> Unix socket /run/monit.socket connection error -- Connection refused

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have received no answers, I conclude that unfortunately, `monit` is not well supported by the community and possibly not used that much.

I came up with the following bash script that serves my purpose:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
if ps -C python3 &> /dev/null
then :
else
sudo systemctl poweroff
fi
sleep 60
done
```

Here `:` is a no-op that returns true,

```
while :
do
...
done
```

is an infinite loop, `python3` is the program I am monitoring, `ps -C python3` is a command that returns true if `python3` is running (possibly with any parameters) and false otherwise, `&> /dev/null` discards the output of this command (otherwise it is printed every minute in the terminal), `sudo systemctl poweroff` is the command that powers off my computer, `sleep 60` puts the script to sleep for 1 minute.

I have put this code in a file, named it `monitor`, made it executable and run it as follows:

```
./monitor & disown
```

Here `&` runs the script in the background and `disown` allows the script to continue running even after the terminal from which I started it, is closed.